# vb.net deleting a label and textbox at runtime

Tags: vb.net

So i have a class that creates a new label and textbox when it is called. The names of each label and textbox are in a continues order counting upward using a variable called `i`:

- `"Label" & i` creates the name Label1 and `"Textbox" & i` creates the name Textbox1
- `i += 1`

And so on. Now i want to add a procedure that deletes the last label and textbox using `i`. I have tried to make this procedure using the lines of code below but this doesnt work as the string cannot be converted to system.windows.forms.control :

`Form1.Controls.Remove("Label" & i)
 Form1.Controls.Remove("Textbox" & i)
 i -= 1`

`Controls` is a list of controls using the line of code:
`Public controls As List(Of Control)`

Basically i need a way to delete a label and textbox using the variable `i` in the class. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try to put your controls inside a panel

Comment: Be careful.  Removing is not disposing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
Form1.Controls.RemoveByKey("Label" & i)
Form1.Controls.RemoveByKey("Textbox" & i)
```

This does not work if you have these controls tucked in `GroupBox`, `Panel`, or some other container on your form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding your controls into a panel, and then delete it as this link suggests (it's quite like what you tried, but inside a panel):

[Removing Dynamically created controls in Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752260/removing-dynamically-created-controls-in-panel)